# Using iptables to redirect ip address

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have the requirement on a Linux system where the Linux device is using RSYNC to sync data to another Linux machine. This is working fine at the moment, however I need to move one of the machines to a different data centre.

Is it possible, using iptables to configure the machine such that all calls to (for example) local address 192.168.100.230 now are actually sent to a public address on the internet?

Answer (score 17):

IP forwarding needs to enabled: edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and ensure that the line `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` is there and not commented out.

Then you need to execute this command:

> iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d [ipaddress1] -j DNAT --to-destination [ipaddress2]

Where `ipaddress1` is the address that you want redirecting to `ipaddress2`.

Note - this command doesn't survive a reboot.

Comment: to complete this:  

    iptables-save >/somepath/iptables.save
    
      Add to cron upon start up  iptables-restore </somepath/iptables.save

Comment: @cybernard's comment should be added to the answer.

Answer (score -3):

The client connects to the old address `192.168.100.230`, and the new address maybe changed, for example `192.168.100.240`. You can do port forwarding with ssh tunnel instead of iptables.

```
ssh -TNnfaq -L 192.168.100.230:22:192.168.100.240:22 user@localhost
```

or

```
ssh -L 192.168.100.230:22:192.168.100.240:22 user@localhost # for test
```

All requests send to `192.168.100.230:22` with forward to `192.168.100.240:22`. You do not need `root` if port number is greater than 1024.