# Using IPtables to redirect IP address range to port range

Tags: networking, iptables

I'm trying to set up an IPtables rule that will forward all packets to a /22 range to a single IP and port for debugging purposes. Based on the question here [Using iptables to redirect ip address](https://superuser.com/questions/681705/using-iptables-to-redirect-ip-address) I was able to extract this command

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d [ipaddress1] -j DNAT --to-destination [ipaddress2]
```

Right now, my command looks something like this

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 5.5.5.0/22 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1:5001
```

Should I be using --dport instead, or does formatting it with a colon work?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: semicolon? You're using a colon (and that's correct, as you can see in the DNAT section of the man page iptables or iptables-extensions in more recent versions).  Is it not working as expected? What's your question really?

Comment: @wurtel Sorry, my mistake, I meant a colon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

In order to specify a port number, you need to specify the protocol as either UDP or TCP. Adding -m udp made it work